# Give the project result to the client in asp

Tags: asp.net

I have a basic question

I started to work with asp for a client, and I built some pages with buttons and grids and so on, and now I want to give him the result of the work.

How do I do it?

In a "normal" application - I give him the exe file and all the dlls, but in asp I didn't found any of this, so what I give to him?

thanks

Comment: Just publish the web application to file system, and give it to client.

Comment: can you  be specific? what is "publish", and what do you mean "file system"

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/1y1404zt(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Continue from comment ...**

Right click on web project, and click on **Publish...**

[image]

Then create a new profile, and select **File System** at Publish method.

[image]